# Manipulação de arquivos zip

Tags: php

Eu tenho um arquivo zip é dentro dele eu tenho algumas imagens que também estão zipados. Como faço pra ter acesso a essas imagens com php?
São dois níveis de zip.

Comment: Use algo como [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php). Pode ler a documentação, tentar fazer alguma coisa e, se não conseguir, voltar aqui, [edit] a pergunta e adicionar os detalhes pertinentes. Talvez a sua pergunta seja reaberta.

Comment: Dá uma olhada neste link e testa as funções: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.zip.php